# Изменил цену на приложение в Google Play на бесплатно. Как вернуть?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Сделал случайно платное приложение бесплатным. Как вернуть всё обратно?

В кабинете разработчика случайно изменил цену от 50,00 руб на 0,00 руб.

Как вернуть обратно цену 50,00 руб. ??

p.s: сбросится ли счетчик скачиваний и отзывы, если залить с новым названием пакета?. Просто у меня есть бесплатная версия приложения на гугл плее, и платная версия, которую я нечаянно сделал бесплатной... Как мне быть?

Answer (score 2):

*Если вы сделали приложение бесплатным, то*

Что следует знать

**Платное приложение можно сделать бесплатным.**

**Бесплатное приложение нельзя сделать платным. Чтобы получать доход от приложения, вам потребуется опубликовать его с новым названием пакета, а затем указать цену.**

*Если изменили цену в платном приложении, то*

Как изменить цены по умолчанию для платного приложения

> Вы можете обновить цены для определенных стран с учетом текущего
>   обменного курса и местных особенностей ценообразования. Для этого
>   сделайте следующее:
>
> 1. Установите флажки рядом с нужными странами.
> 2. Выберите Обновить курсы валют.
>
> Чтобы установить собственную местную цену:
>
> 1. Рядом с нужной страной нажмите Изменить.
> 2. Введите цену.
> 3. Нажмите Применить.

[Источник](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?visit_id=1-636492051063386451-632209633&rd=1#paid_free)

Comment: Не вижу никаких кнопок с названием "Обновить курсы валют".  С новым названием пакета если опубликовать, то сбросятся все отзывы и т.п ?

Comment: да, все сбросится

Comment: то есть я сделал непоправимое, и даже через поддержку Google play вернуть обратно цену не получится?

Comment: @Антон Сомневаюсь. Попробуйте. Может все не так плохо, может все таки цену только поменяли

Comment: так я и поменял только цену

Comment: @Антон. Обратитесь в Службу Поддержки